# What is the meaning of $f_{n}(t) = f(nt)$?

Tags: real-analysis

From Rudin Ch. 7 exercise.  Let {$f_{n}$} be a sequence of functions.   What is the meaning of $f_{n}(t) = f(nt)$?  This comes from a problem in which this is one of the hypotheses.

[edit] I should have included this. $f$ is real-valued and continuous on $ \mathbb{R}$.  The previously mentioned is a property of $f$, and the other hypothesis is that $f_{n}$ is equicontinuos on $[0,1]$.  The book question is "what conclusions can we draw about $f$?"  My question is simply what does $f_{n}(t) = f(nt)$ tell us about $f$

Comment: $f_n = f \circ g_n,$ where $g_n(t) = nt.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f_n(t)=f(nt)$ then unless $f$ is constant, $f_n$ will vary more rapidly as $n$ grows. (Think of $f(x)=\sin(x)$ for example.) Specifically, if $f_n$ are equicontinuous then $f$ must actually be constant. The idea of the proof is to take arbitrary $x,y,\varepsilon$, then note that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f_n(x/n)-f_n(y/n)|$ for all $n$. Then use the definition of equicontinuity to force $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.